# Why is MongoDB Repository null when running a Java Swing application with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, swing

I am trying to build a Swing application using MongoDB with Spring Boot. I am using the Spring Boot MongoDB artifact so it's all with Spring libraries.

The error I get when I run my app is: `Cannot invoke "com.walkersorlie.qbshippingservice.repositories.ProductRepository.findAll()" because "this.productRepository" is null`.

This is the class that creates the Spring application and then runs the Swing app:

```
public class QbshippingserviceApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApplicationUI.class)
                .headless(false)
                .run(args);

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            ApplicationUI ex = ctx.getBean(ApplicationUI.class);
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });

    }
}
```

and this is the class that creates the Swing JFrame:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class ApplicationUI extends JFrame {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CustomProductRepository customProductRepository;

    private List<Product> productList;
    private JList<String> jListProductsList;

    public ApplicationUI() {
        createUIComponents();
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here

        this.jListProductsList = new JList<>();
        try {
            this.productList = productRepository.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.jListProductsList.setListData((String[]) this.productList.stream()
                .map(Product::getDescription)
                .toArray());
    }
}
```

I have `@Autowired` the Mongo repository I implemented but the Beans doesn't seem to load.

I think that this Swing class is outside the context of the Spring application so that's why the MongoDB repository Bean is `null` but I'm not sure how to fix that. If the way I'm running the Swing application with the `EventQueue` is the problem I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: can you show the code of your repository?

Comment: @Stultuske The repository code is irrelevant, and the OP is not using `new`. The problem is sequencing.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- "the repository code is irrelevant"? Why is that? Because without looking at it, you can tell it is correctly annotated and configured? I was mistaken on the instantiation though, you were right about that.

Comment: @Stultuske Because if it weren't getting registered as a Spring bean, the error would be a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, not an NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the repository from within your constructor, which is before Spring has had a chance to get a reference to the `ApplicationUI` instance and inject it. Preferably, eliminate the field injection and make your dependencies constructor parameters. If that absolutely can't be done, you'll need to make your `createUiComponents()` method `@PostConstruct` instead.

Comment: Ok that makes sense! How exactly do I pass the dependency (Mongo repository) to the `ApplicationUI` constructor? Not sure of the code to make that happen

Comment: @WalkerSorlie You make it an argument just like with any other method.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. How do I pass the argument in the main method in `QbshippingserviceApplication`? I don't explicitly create the `Application UI` reference (like `new ApplicationUI()`) so I'm not sure how to pass arguments to the `ApplicationUI` constructor

Comment: @WalkerSorlie Spring does it by magic.